# Cannot delete file folder using normal methods

Tags: 18.04, permissions, hard-drive, directory, ntfs

See pasted screen shot.Video Home-2 folder shows "content empty" when you right click on it.I must delete it and it gives the included error message. The UUIC internal drive partition type is:
-NTFS/ExFat/HPFS
-Content-NTFS
=Mounted at (UUID)
Your help will be appreciated.
Mel Reade

[image]

Comment: Have your ntfs partition checked and fixed under MS Windows before reconnecting it to Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi Vanadium: Ubuntu utilities says partition one is fine and no issues. No other partitions. This is a storage disk only. Capacity is 1 TB and is 50% full. Disk has been ok for years until said video file was installed. Not being a Windows user I am not sure how to proceed with your suggestion or if that is the only option. Thanks,

Comment: If  you do not use Windows, then prefer to reformat to ext4 or another native file system. Only Windows can fully check ntfs drives. Eventually check the drive with the linux tool ntfsfix.

Comment: Hi Vanadium: Thanks for your replies. I thought I might be able to avoid reformat etc. but you have confirmed some of my earlier thoughts. I will follow your advice and will do this. Much appreciated and stay safe.